# How to add Foreground Colour option to custom block

Tags: block-editor

I'm trying to add a custom Foreground Colour setting to a custom block I'm building.

I have Background Colour being added via Block Supports, and would like the Foreground Colour option to appear in the same Inspector Panel as the other colour options. However, I can't find any documentation on how to do this.

[image: Standard Block Color Panel with Background Color option]

(Standard Block Colour Panel - I want my foreground colour control to appear here)

[image: Custom Block Color Panel with Foreground colour option]

(This is my current custom foreground colour control)

Following this post: https://awhitepixel.com/how-to-add-color-settings-to-your-custom-gutenberg-block/, I've managed to add a Foreground Colour control, but I can't see how to place it in the standard colour panel under the Appearance tab.

What's the best practice for doing this? Has the method in the article linked been superseded, or is that still the go-to approach?